# unexpected execution of update query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table in MySql as:

```
        CREATE TABLE products (
          sub_product_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          sub_product_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
          price int(10) NOT NULL,
          available_qty int(10) NOT NULL,
          image1_path varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          image2_path varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '~//uploaded_img//not_uploaded.jpg',
          image3_path varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '~//uploaded_img//not_uploaded.jpg',
          image4_path varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '~//uploaded_img//not_uploaded.jpg',
          image5_path varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '~//uploaded_img//not_uploaded.jpg',
          shipping_details varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'shipping details not specified yet',
          price_details varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'price details not specified yet',
          products_brand varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'product''s brand not specified yet',
          category_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
          sub_category_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          description varchar(500) NOT NULL,
          product_name varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'product''s name not specified yet',
          title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
          user_id int(10) NOT NULL,
          date_of_creation date NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (sub_product_id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

my first query is:

```
    insert into products (sub_product_name,price,available_qty,image1_path,products_brand,category_name,sub_category_name,description,product_name,title,user_id,date_of_creation) values('','14','45','~//uploaded_img//AD_IMG63.jpg','','Electronics','Camera Digicams','Product Description here','','Product Title Here','43','2011/04/03')
```

this query is executing

the sub_product_id generated on execution of above insert statement is 38

now my application needs to fire this update query after the previous insert query

```
    update products set image2_path='~//uploaded_img//AD_IMG64.jpg' and image3_path='~//uploaded_img//AD_IMG65.jpg' and image4_path='~//uploaded_img//AD_IMG66.jpg' and image5_path='~//uploaded_img//AD_IMG67.jpg' and shipping_details='Shipping Details here' and price_details='Price Details here' and description='Product Description here' where sub_product_id=38
```

but the result is unexpected:

all the fields value is not setting accordingly as stated in the above update query

i am getting the result something like this:
   the image2_path fields value becomes 0
   and all the rest fields value remains the same un-updated

please help me find the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
update products set image2_path='..' and image3_path='..'
```

try

```
update products set image2_path='..', image3_path='..'
```

Comment: oh great it worked sometimes i become too restless and i make minor mistakes like writing silly wrong sql queries ha ha...o thanks a lot sir